# Matlab reading values from excel file

Tags: excel, matlab, xlsread

Hi I'm using function xlsread() in matlab.

```
H2O = xlsread('Water.xlsx','K2:K101')
```

this is not working

```
H2O = xlsread('Water.xlsx','A2:A101')
```

is working.

is there some limit which columns can be read?

Comment: Do you get any error message? What is "not working"?

Comment: it will not create array of data H2O will be 0x0, but if you use second example array will be created 100x1

Comment: Do you have an data in the `K` column?

Comment: Does column K contain numeric data? Is it really numeric data? Did you check the other outputs of `xlsread`?

Comment: i did figure it out. Data in excel had decimal poin and matlab use comma for decimal point so I just change excel file (find and replace) all dots (.) for commas (,)

Comment: @user3720192 : That's not true.  The commas and dots for determining what is a decimal point is determined by your system settings.  You can also override this behaviour in MATLAB so there is no need for you to manually change your Excel sheet.